# zeromq and c# binding

Tags: c#, binding, zeromq

I am a C# developer and I am learning [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) api right now. By reading various articles, I found that I have to use C# Bindings.

The main problem for me is where to start. I followed steps on this [link](http://www.mansysadmin.com/2011/03/02/using-zeromq-framework-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial/) and put libzmq.dll under C:\windows\system32\ and I have clrzmq.dll and clrzmq-ext.dll referenced in visual studio project. I tried first two samples from zeromq guide and it works fine.

I got confused when I show these links.
[link1](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq/blob/master/README.md)
[link2](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3aclr) (please scroll down to example.

As shown in link1, I don't see any method like Context.CreateContext() and CreateSocket()
As shown in link2, subscriber does not have event that notifies about the received data.

Can someone point why I am not seeing above things on my machine?

Thanks,

mChicago

Answer (score 2):

In your question you say there is no Context.CreateContext()

If you are using the clrzmq bindings, the call is

```
using(var context = ZmqContext.Create())
...
```

Perhaps you misread it?

You second question is actually about some ambiguity on the C# bindings page. The example you point out is actually for the ZeroMQ Interop library, and not clrzmq (which is referenced at the top of the page.) The defining line between those two sections is kind of confusing.

Hope this helps.